# Looking for a way to make a cursed swarm item (squirrels, rats, flies...) while the item is slowly taking the person over

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew, curses, villain

[image]One of my players has a wicked idea for a story hook:
He wants some kind of cursed item, that has like another person, god,... in it that slowly takes him over.

Every time he does take over, he emits an aura of necrotic/poison energy
that affects everyone around him, friend or foe.

It also affects nature quite heavily and it gives him a swarm with creatures that are available in that region(rats in a city, squirrels in a forest, locust in a field,...)
it does however destroy nature itself hard with quite harsh , food rotten, crops rotten,...

The big idea is that slowly he turns out into a bbeg that the party can kill, or try to save.
Looks like that could be a fun idea.

How would you guys make an item like that, do we increase the number of animals or level or on how far he is gone, what are downsides we could give it to balance it?

Really looking forward for all your valuable input!

See the example.above, is this balanced?
Tried to fit it with conjure animals

Sincerely,

Adrian & Laurens

Comment: For this site, it might be better to provide a draft version of the item, and ask for critique about game balance. We're not a forum site, and don't usually do open ended "idea generation", where you have some idea and people come up with possible implementations: the site is about providing the objectively best answer, and it is very hard to say what is the right or best answer for these kind of questions.

Comment: Just for a bit of a side note barely related to the question - is the rest of the party okay with PVP? What happens if one of them casts Remove Curse on the object and takes it from them when it becomes apparent or problematic? Homebrewing a cursed item that causes the occasional plague sounds cool, but I would be hesitant to make it a primary plot hook and turning the PC into the BBEG.

Comment: @Nobody the hobgoblin, wi will try to form a draft, we have no idea how to put it into 5e and it definitely does not have to the best, but we have no idea how to begin crafting a thing like this but we will try!

TheLittlePeace, they are deffinitly ok with pvp,!
they also have chanses to beat it in our opinion without to much combat, 
but they are in for it, hlf of the players are muderhobos anyway ;-p

Comment: I added an example maybe that helps :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is very interesting.

The item could be a necklace with a pendant in the shape of a locust.
It would cause rashes to appear on the cursed creature's body and these rashes would hatch into locusts that will multiply and accompany the creature, making it impossible for it to live in society because the locusts want to eat everything around.

Since you want to make a villain it is possible for him to learn how to control the locusts in battle and get stronger by creating extra swarms and abilities like a locust armor that provide resistance to certain damage and increase armor.

Also, since you wants to make redemption possible, it would be interesting if he was a child when he was cursed and the characters discover his history.
You could also create an item that the characters look for it that will attract all the locusts and make it possible to remove the necklace and end the curse, something like a "harvest bowl" that has the power to improve the crops of a region and that attracts those magical locusts into it taking them to another plane.

I hope I didn't deviate from the purpose of the thread.

Comment: we really like he idea!
do he then get damage when they rip out of its body as a downsize?

and does he get more and more locust depending on it's level?

Comment: I believe it would be better for him to constantly be with 1 level of exhaustion due to the constant outbreak of heat rash than to take damage. In this way, it has a great limitation, but it would not be necessary to calculate the damage caused and its evolution.

Comment: ooh yeah exhausting sound greta, we are runnign arround with it know, i think to give him x amount of Swarm of Insects dependend on level (think of lookign at summon animals to see how much, and he can use each swarm for offensive or defensive capabilites

Comment: @LaurensWolf We generally suggest you wait at least 24 hours of posting to accept an answer - it gives the question the opportunity to get the attention it needs, while also encouraging others to answer, potentially bringing in more concrete answers.

Comment: noted thank you! and sorry! removed it

Comment: _"...and these rashes would hatch into locusts..."_  Well, that's horrifying.  And excellent.

Comment: Maybe something like this?